# problems importing pandas2ri from rpy2.objects

Tags: python, pandas, rpy2

I have been struggling with this import for a while.
I would like to use the pandas2ri module of rpy2.objects but importing it seems to fail.

my imports are as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
```

I get the following error (on the last import):

```
File "my_file.py", line 31, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
  File "/<path>/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py", line 137, in <module>
    pandas.BooleanDtype: functools.partial(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 208, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute '{}'".format(name))
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'BooleanDtype'
```

Similar problems I found online were due to missing R HOME env variables, but those are set in my case and shouldn't be the problem.

The code I am using was originally written in python2 and I work with python3. Although this shouldn't be a problem for the importing since I installed the most recent versions of rpy2, pandas.

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you have the most recent version of pandas? I can't think of any reason `BooleanDtype` would be missing other than pandas being old. It was introduced in version v1.0.0. One way you could double-check is to insert the line `pd.show_versions()` right above the line `import rpy2.robjects as robjects`.

Comment: @NickODell, you were right, I asked my question too fast. Upgrading pandas resolved the issue. Thank you!